# How to complete async call before loading silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight application that uses WCF, and I would like to make a WCF call to load some data before the usercontrol is loaded so that I could use the data with an autocompletebox. Any suggestions as to how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your user interface will be suitable to use a loading indicator or a progress bar. If you can use loading indicator, then it might be a good option to display the busy / loading indicator while the async call is in progress. That would disable the user from clicking on the dropdown or any other control while the data is being retrieved from the WCF service.

Comment: This approach seems easiest. I tossed in a busyindicator and set it to true, ran the async call, and set busyindicator to false. Works just fine for my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the async call in the `Application_Startup()` method of your `App.xaml.cs` file, and set `RootVisual` in your async callback instead of in `Application_Startup()`.

Comment: Using this method, if I want to hook up my autocompletebox on my usercontrol to the data returned from the WCF call, how would I do that? The instance of the usercontrol wouldn't have been created yet.

Answer (score 0):

All WCF service calls in Silverlight are asynchronous. I've learned to use Lambdas and a very useful class called [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) (which is a wrapper for an event and a delegate).
Using the application startup as RobSiklos suggested would work great for getting it before showing the control. This shows the code that could also work inside of the userControl loaded event, incorporating a loading overlay (you could use a border with centered text that goes over the whole app or a Silverlight toolkit control). This approach will give more immediate feedback to the user, especially if your data service call will take a longer time.

```
public MyUserControl : UserControl
{

 public MyUserControl()
 {
  this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(View_Loaded);
 }

 void View_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
  // start showing loading overlay
  MyService service = new Service(...);
  service.GetDataCompleted += (o, args) =>
  {
    var data = args.Results;
    // hide loading overlay
  }
 }
}
```